# Is Apple's default Privacy settings GDPR compliant?

Tags: gdpr

I recently realized that some apps were able to "link" my identity to Facebook. I checked my [off facebook activity](https://www.facebook.com/off_facebook_activity/) and could see some apps that I've never given my email.

Investigating further, I believe it boils down to a setting that's set under `Settings > Privacy > Advertising` on my iPhone. There's a way to either reset the advertising identifier, or `Limit Ad Tracking`, which I believe prevents this completely (perhaps generating a unique identifier each time?)

"Solving" this was easy obviously by limiting ad tracking, but I'm wondering: How come it's not limited by default? Shouldn't GDPR protect me from this kind of default? Shouldn't Apple [get my explicit consent](https://gdpr.eu/gdpr-consent-requirements/) for something like this? I don't recall having given such consent...

UPDATE:

I contacted Apple's privacy team, and they seem to think this isn't personal information under the GDPR

> We would like to reiterate that the advertising identifier we have perviously [sic] referred to is not associated with your Apple ID. It is randomly generated on your device. Information collected in association with an advertising identifier is not personally identifiable and thus consent does not arise under the GDPR.
>
> Apple does not sell or otherwise transmit any personally identifiable information to third parties.

I personally [beg to differ](https://blog.gingerlime.com/2020/does-apple-care-about-your-privacy/).

Very curious to know what the experts on here think and what can be done about it.

Comment: Thank you @schroeder I didn't know / never used law.se but I guess it makes more sense here. When I was working in security, we did deal with regulations, so there's quite a bit of overlap. I guess I just posted where I was more comfortable :)

Comment: We made the decision that questions about "is this compliant?" would be better here

Comment: Apple does not seem to understand the difference between personal data (GDPR) and personally identifiable information (a US concept). I think an advertising identifier is clearly personal data, see [What are identifiers and related factors?](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/what-is-personal-data/what-are-identifiers-and-related-factors/) and the linked info. You can file a complaint at a DPA [example](https://noyb.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/AppleMusic_Complaint_geschw%C3%A4rzt.pdf) or go to court yourself.